# T-SQL - Selecting amount of rows created each day over period of time using DateTime column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm still fairly new to T-SQL, Stored Procedures and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

I have a table called **HistoryDetails** in which I store a history of calls made over the past 6 months. It has a **DateTime** column to know when a call was made. I'm creating a dashboard where I would like to create a list of the amount of calls made each day.

Here is a simplified example of the data in my database:

```
------------------------------------------------------
| Id | DateTime                | Message             |
|----+-------------------------+---------------------|
| 1  | 2017-02-27 11:52:44.723 | Room 101 called you |
|----+-------------------------+---------------------|
| 2  | 2017-02-27 11:53:58.689 | Room 101 called you |
|----+-------------------------+---------------------|
| 3  | 2017-02-28 10:41:30.440 | Room 102 called you |
------------------------------------------------------
```

**The result I would like** is a list of days and the amount of calls made (rows created) on each day. (my database keeps data for 6 months, everything older than 6 months is deleted)

For example:

```
----------------------------------------
| Date        | Amount of calls (rows) |
|-------------+------------------------|
| 2017-02-27  | 2                      |
|-------------+------------------------|
| 2017-02-28  | 1                      |
|-------------+------------------------|
| 2017-03-01  | 5                      |
|-------------+------------------------|
| 2017-02-02  | 2                      |
----------------------------------------
```

The SQL query I have been able to make so far is only able to return the amount of calls made (rows created) for one day, here is the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM HistoryDetails
WHERE (AlarmHistoryDetails.DateTime BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()), 0) AND DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()), 1))
```

This results in:

```
(No column name)
22
```

Which is not exactly what I need.

What is the query required to get the result I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `group by`:

```
SELECT CAST(hd.DateTime as DATE) as dte, COUNT(*)
FROM HistoryDetails hd
GROUP BY CAST(hd.DateTime as DATE)
ORDER BY dte;
```

Answer (score 0):

> You want GROUP BY CLAUSE:

```
SELECT CAST(DateTime as DATE) as [Date], COUNT(*) As AmountOfCalls
FROM HistoryDetails
GROUP BY CAST(DateTime as DATE)
ORDER BY [Date];
```